# Make button validate form and open a link

Tags: html

I want with a simple button in a form, validate the form and at the same time, open a new tab with "link.com". But when I click on the button, the form is validate but the the "link.com" does't open. I don't know how to do that correctly ... Thank you

```html
<form class="form-row" action="mail.php" method="post">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-12 mb-2 mb-md-0">
    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="email..." name="mail" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary btnoffre">Je veux en recruter !</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
    <a href="link.com"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary btnoffre">Je veux être recruté.e !</button></a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add onsubmit to your form:

```
<form class="form-row" action="mail.php" method="post" onsubmit="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank')" >
```

Comment: Yes, it altmost good, but I want to open a new tab with the link only with the second button

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want one button that does 2 things? 
Maybe some JavaScript piece would help here? :

Get the correct BUTTON element - one inside :

```
const BUTTON = document.querySelector("div button");
```

And listen for click event, when it goes, trigger function that opens new tab? :

```
BUTTON.addEventListener('click', function(){ window.open(link.com, '_blank');
win.focus(); }, false);
```

Wonder if sth like this would help with this?